# HTML5 audio louder while playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

I've got a code like this:

```
    var upsound = new Audio('sound/upsound.mp3')
    upsound.loop = true;
    upsound.play();
```

I would like to get the volume louder while the audio is playing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `volume` property for this, which goes from 0.0 (mute) to 1.0 (full volume):

```
upsound.volume = 1.0;
```

**Edit:**

If you want to set the volume up after a certain delay, you can simply use a timeout:

```
usound.volume = 0.0; // Start with no sound

setTimeout(function() {
   usound.volume = 1.0; // Increase the volume after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I don't think volume attribute is incorporated in browser till now.. Let me know if I am wrong...I have included the link below.

Comment: I think the Mozilla table is a mistake. I've just tried it on Firefox 29 and the volume property works fine. According to caniuse.com, all major browsers fully supports (and not just partially support) the `audio` element - http://caniuse.com/audio

Comment: Thank you, but I knew the property volume, I wanted to know if there is a method to start with mute volume and get it louder while playing.

Comment: @user3653589, in that case you can start with `upsound.volume = 0.0;` and set the volume louder later on. When you say "while playing", do you mean some way to change the volume interactively? Or after a certain delay?

Comment: After a certain delay.

Comment: @user3653589, for this you could use `setTimeout`. I've updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Volume attribute for audio should be the solution but until now, it seems like it is not been incorporated in any browsers. Check [Browser Compatibility for Audio files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). You can use something like this which will give you controls to use during playing but through coding, it is not yet possible.

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="foo.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: As of 2020, this is now possible.